# Can't enable Raspberry pi Camera

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, camera

I have encountered a problem which am not suppose to but i inserted my raspberry pi camera in the the camera slot on the raspberry and powered the raspberry pi but didn’t get the window option that shows where to enable camera.

I did the “sudo apt-get update”, and “sudo apt-get upgrade” , and then “sudo raspi-config” in the terminal but still couldn’t see enable the camera option.

I even went to the preference and selected raspberry pi configuration and under interface i enabled the camera but still couldn't get the camera enabled.

The raspberry pi camera shows it is powered when I insert into the camera port which is at the back of raspberry pi but doesn't power on when I insert the raspberry pi camera into the port thats close to the HDMI port.

Please anyone know whats wrong please help me out cheers.

Comment: Please edit your question to include paragraphs, punctuation, and proper capitalization.

Answer (score 4):

The camera port is next to the hdmi connector, the other similar looking port is for a display:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-picamera/worksheet/

If your camera has been enabled then the python scripts in the link will get you some pictures or video. If you get a MMAl out of resources error then the ribbon isn't seated right, either on the pi or on the camera.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

you might want to try a

```
~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

assuming you're using python try

```
~ $ vim camera.py

from picamera import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.capture('image.jpg')
print('image captured!')
```

then run it

```
~ $ python camera.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem. My camera was enabled but while running script it was asking me to enable the camera. Then I found out that it is because of loose camera connections. There are three connection points as shown in *figure 1* and *figure 2*. Mine was loose at the point shown in figure 2.

Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1 Ribbon cable connectors]

Figure 2.

[image: Figure 2: Camera to PCB connector]

So, to solve your problem please check connections at all **three** points.

After checking all connections use the following code to check the working of the camera. The camera will show the preview for 5 seconds.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the latest Raspbian, bookworm, automatically configures the camera by default, so the camera no longer shows up in the interface list.  On my Pi Zero W v1.1, it reports the camera is missing with the following:

```
~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

However, I can see it is connected by running:

```
~ $ libcamera-still --list-cameras
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : ov5647 [2592x1944 10-bit GBRG] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36)
    Modes: 'SGBRG10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [58.92 fps - (16, 0)/2560x1920 crop]
                             1296x972 [43.25 fps - (0, 0)/2592x1944 crop]
                             1920x1080 [30.62 fps - (348, 434)/1928x1080 crop]
                             2592x1944 [15.63 fps - (0, 0)/2592x1944 crop]
```

So no config, just take a pic:

```
libcamera-still -o snap.jpg
```